# How do you escape a column name in Google visualisation API query language?

Tags: google-visualization, google-query-language

I have a Google sheet which generates an error in the following expression:

```
=query(Capacity!A5:FE135,"SELECT C,A WHERE "&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,match(D2,Capacity!A1:FE1,0)+2,4),"1","")&" = '"&C2&"' AND "&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,match(D2,Capacity!A1:FE1,0),4),"1","")&" = 1 ORDER BY C")
```

for a single, specific input value (a date) at `D2`.

Essentially, the purpose of the code is to find the column location of the date at `D2` in a second sheet (Capacity) and put the values of that column in that sheet into column `C` in the current sheet, while also selecting only rows that match on a second column. When the date is set to a specific value, however, the expression will not evaluate.

On breaking this massive expression down into its component parts, it turns out the problem is caused by this expression:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,match(D2,Capacity!A1:FE1,0)+2,4),"1","")
```

which, for the offending date, is returning column `BY`.

This means the expression being evaluated in Google Visualization API query language is:

```
SELECT C,A WHERE BY = '' AND BW = 1 ORDER BY C
```

but the query language sees `BY` as a reserved word, not a column, and barfs.

How can I escape the column name somehow to make it clear that it is to be considered a column name?

Answer (score 1):

The way is to surround the offending portion with back-quotes (as I used to make text `monospaced` here):

```
=query(Capacity!A5:FE135,"SELECT C,A WHERE `"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,match(D2,Capacity!A1:FE1,0)+2,4),"1","")&"` = '"&C2&"' AND `"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,match(D2,Capacity!A1:FE1,0),4),"1","")&"` = 1 ORDER BY C")
```

so the query will look like

```
SELECT C,A WHERE `BY` = '' AND `BW` = 1 ORDER BY C
```

I assume this will help when the sheet grows so big that we're on column `IF` as well.